# Windows 10: How to change the bluetooth taskbar icon?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I prefer having my taskbar icons black and white, because it's clean and snazzy. Unfortunately, the blue Bluetooth icon ruins it for me. Is there any way to change the Bluetooth taskbar icon to one of my own making?

[image: Taskbar icons]

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any way to change this icon because that is part of basic Windows Devices.

But you can remove the icon (much like the Printer icon is normally not there).

Settings, Devices, Bluetooth, and on the right hand screen, scroll down for More Bluetooth options, and then there is a option to turn the icon off.

Bluetooth attachment (pairing) is done in Devices anyway.

You can also just hide the icon so it does not appear in your System Tray.

I do this on my machines (all of which have Bluetooth).

[image]